# How to create waterproof dog kennel floor?

Tags: flooring, construction, design

I want to build a dog kennel that is 4' x 8'. I want the flooring to be able to be cleaned out by using a water hose. I was planning on creating a concrete slab with a raised edge around it. I'm not sure if there are better methods to do this.

**Requirements:**

- Floor/foundation must not leak from the edges except for a designated area to allow drainage.
- Must be something that can be easily cleaned with a hose.
- Can't cause future water damage to structure on the slab.

This is a rough design of what I would like the kennel to look like (side view). [image]

Comment: A drain is of course good for flushing away urine and *traces* of feces after the main mass is picked up. But you should not flush large amounts of dog feces into the surface drainage. Urine is sterile (but somewhat smelly) feces are decidedly *not* sterile and are very, very smelly. In actual use feces deposited on the floor of this kennel (excepting *traces* left after pickup) should not be flushed down this drain unless the drain would be connected to the house sanitary sewer or the septic tank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea of using a concrete slab is a good start. Since you want to have a raised edge the assumption is you want containment, and since you also want to be able to hose it down you want a draining/washable system.

Sounds very similar to what a food processing plant would do - so there are [surface treatments you can make to the concrete that will allow you to wash it down](http://www.florock.net/industrial-flooring-systems/food-beverage-processing-epoxy-flooring-solutions/chemical-washdown-areas/) even with chemicals.

Your slab should be poured with a grade - slant towards your drain system - and depending on how you want to handle that drainage i.e. sewer system or other methods should determine how high up the slab should be for proper drainage (for example a pump system or gravity system).

Given your requirements , for the drain you might want to consider [a catch system or a trench style drain](https://www.google.com/search?q=Stainless%20Steel%20Drain%20with%20Catch&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=Stainless%20Steel%20floor%20Drain%20with%20Catch) (basically this is a grate with a drain underneath) - the slab should slope its grade towards the drain. Or you can use a simple floor drain with a [removable cage](https://www.katom.com/009-FT2.html?zmam=29342707&zmas=1&zmac=32&zmap=009-FT2&utm_source=google&utm_medium=adwords&utm_campaign=CSE&gclid=CIf5wPjR0dMCFUg7gQodTdMGEA) to catch debris (so your drain does not get clogged - with hair or other things).

You should use an Epoxy type resin coating to cover the slab there are many types available but if you look for washdown epoxy floor coatings there are several manufacturers and types available.

[Stonhard](https://www.stonhard.com/)

[Florock](http://www.florock.net/industrial-flooring-systems/food-beverage-processing-epoxy-flooring-solutions/chemical-washdown-areas/)